# Draw text or symbol on imageview in android

Tags: android, image, touch, android-imageview

I am developing an app that requires mee to allow user to draw any text on an image shown.
I am not able to get the correct term to search the web- should i call it sensing or call it touch event or what it is a gesture application.
Precisely i want to enable the user to scribble any thing or draw any thing on the image.
I have few ideas like it can use canvas or some overlay element But nothing concrete.

P.S. :
I am using the android 2.2 as target.
I am new to android development.
Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Answering my own first question  :) 
Actually i could not get directly to the solution - but atleast found 2 ways out.

1. You can take 2 imageview's. Allocate the 1st Imageview ( ref it as imageview1 ) with the image source  and then place the 2nd Imageview ( ref it as imageview2 ) on imageview1 , such a way that it covers entire screen ( fill parent - both height and width ) .
   Now in .java file , assign `imageview2.setOnTouchListener(this);` and override the onLoad() method as per your need . Eg.

   `public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

   ```
   int action = event.getAction();
   switch (action) {
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

       oldx = downx = event.getX();
       oldy = downy = event.getY();            
       break;

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

       downx = event.getX();
       downy = event.getY();

       canvas.drawLine(oldx, oldy, downx, downy, paint);
       imgvw.invalidate();

       oldx = downx ;
       oldy = downy ;          
       break;

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
       upx = event.getX();
       upy = event.getY();

       canvas.drawLine(oldx, oldy, upx, upy, paint);
       imgvw.invalidate();

       break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    // SOME CODE THAT YOU WANNA USE 
       break;
   default:
       break;
   }
   return true;
   ```

   }`

> Paint paint = new Paint() ;
>
> paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

This will help to draw on imageview2 but it would seem as if it is been drawn on imageview1 :)

1. The second method is pretty straight forward - 
   Create a new class ( cal it MyImageview ) extending ImageView .
   Now in your activity class, create an object of MyImageView and `setContentView(myImageView(this))`  and attach a `setOnTouchListener(this);` , implement the onTouch method as specified above and this will work fine .